# Finite/Infinite Sets: Prove that if $ B\subseteq A, A$ is infinite, and B is finite, then $A\setminus B $ is infinite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $ B\subseteq A, A$ is infinite, and B is finite, then $A\setminus B $ is infinite.

From http://users.metu.edu.tr/serge/courses/111-2011/textbook-math111.pdf page 313.

Comment: $A = B \cup (A \setminus B)$

Comment: Note that $|B\cup (A\setminus B)|=|B|+|A\setminus B|$

Comment: What have you tried and where are you getting stuck? Have you tried a proof by contradiction using $A = (A \setminus B) \cup B$?

Comment: You subtract finitely many elements from a set which is infinite. Is it possible that there left finitely many elements ?

Answer (score 0):

Here $B \subseteq A$ and $B$ is finite, as $A$ is infinite so $B^{c}$ is infinite also. Hence $$A - B = A \cap B^c$$ is infinite also.

Comment: The intersection of two infinite sets can be finite.

Comment: but $B \subseteq A$, then is it possible?

Comment: No: that's indeed the key!

Answer (score 0):

Prove the equivalent statement

> If $B\subseteq A$, $B$ is finite and $A\setminus B$ is finite, then $A$ is finite.

Hint: $A=B\cup(A\setminus B)$